# Find package given module name in Julia?

Tags: module, julia

Say I have a bunch of packages loaded in the REPL or somewhere and I'm playing around with code that references a cool module `CoolModule`. How can I figure out what package it belongs to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a module defines several sub-modules and assume `CoolModule` is one of them, you can find what the module/package it belongs to via `@which`:

```
julia> whos()
                          Base  23813 KB     Module
                          Core   2858 KB     Module
                          Main  26440 KB     Module
                           ans  23865 KB     Module

julia> @which Sys
Base
```

Here, `Sys` is a sub-module of `Base`.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know that `@which` also worked on modules. Awesome!

Comment: +1; I misunderstood the question. :) There is also the `module_parent` function for modules with submodules.

Answer (score 2):

I would find it very odd if the module name wasn't the same as the package (indeed I assumed the module name and file name **had** to be the same until you asked this ) ... but if you must, you can use `grep` from your terminal (if you're on linux),e.g:

```
~/.julia/v0.6 $ grep "module CoolModule" -r
```

This will show you the file where it is defined. E.g. for module `StatsBase` on my system:

```
tasos@tasos-VanB ~/.julia/v0.6 $ grep "module StatsBase" -r
StatsBase/src/StatsBase.jl:module StatsBase
```

Windows has a grep-like command called `find` too. (or you can just download grep for windows).